# Error while building INSTALL project in OpenTLD installation on windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

- The ***openTLD main project*** was built without errors.
- The ***INSTALL project*** got this error:

> ```
> Error 1   error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
> "E:\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
> if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
> :cmEnd
> endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
> :cmErrorLevel
> exit /b %1
> :cmDone
> if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
> :VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 113
> ```

Here is the ***openTLD project*** ([LINK](https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD/zipball/master)). All other projects have been built without errors.

Comment: Happy new year! Just install and play OpenTTD instead! Or, more seriously, try calling `setlocal
"E:\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake` on the command line to see if cmake gives a more helpful error message.

Comment: Happy New Year to you too ....!
I did this and it helped. The project build required administrative privileges... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You must call

```
setlocal "E:\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
```

on the command line in order to see more helpful error messages. In your case, you got error because it wasn't launched with sufficient privileges.

=> **Run the `INSTALL build with administrative privileges`**